# Google Maps API not rendering in IE9

Tags: google-maps-api-3, internet-explorer-9

I'm wondering what IE9's security settings don't like about this library

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3&sensor=false
```

It and all of the links referenced therein are https://, so my first guess is wrong (non-secure content.)

No JS errors, it just doesn't render in IE9.  ("It" being a fairly standard DIV rendered by a  JS routine that works fine in FF and IE versions up to IE8.)

Sorry I can't post the JS code presently; I'm just checking to see whether there are any known issues with the Google Maps API versus IE9's new security settings.

Answer (score 0):

This has worked for me. After the map has been created add this (replace map for the name of your variable):

```
setTimeout('google.maps.event.trigger(map, "resize");map.setZoom(map.getZoom());', 200);
```

Comment: Thanks, this was an interesting idea but it didn't apply to my particular disappearing map :-(